# Small top border for header while maintaining header's height

Tags: css

I would like to have a small top border on my headers. I did this with `::before` pseudo but the heading height is now messed up because of its absolute positioning. Any element after the heading ignores the heading height because of course the absolute element is removed from document flow.

Is there a better way to achieve this look and feel and maintain the heading height as well? Preferably without positioning?

```css
h3 { position: absolute; }

h3:before {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -5px;
  content:'';
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #C70021;
  width: 20%;
  height: 3px;
  top: 0;
  left:0;
}
```

```html
<h3>My Heading</h3>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec convallis nunc malesuada, aliquam leo nec, auctor sem</p>
```

Comment: It's `::before`, not `:before`, btw. While browsers [_do_ support `:before`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before), I imagine it will be obsoleted eventually.

Comment: Why not do `h3::first-letter { text-decoration: overline #C70021; }` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- To use `position: absolute;` on a child box, such as `::before` or `::after`, or any descendant element, the parent just needs `position: relative;` (instead of the default `position: static;`).

  - So you don't need `position: absolute;` on the `h3`.
- You also have redundant properties set in your `h3::before` rule, btw.

```css
h3 {
  position: relative;
}

h3::before {
  margin-top: -5px;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #C70021;
  width: 20px;
  height: 3px;
  top: 0;
  left:0;
}
```

```html
<h3>My Heading</h3>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec convallis nunc malesuada, aliquam leo nec, auctor sem</p>
```

However, alternative approaches exist, for example this is simpler:

```css
h3::first-letter {
  text-decoration: overline #C70021;
  text-decoration-thickness: 3px;
}
```

```html
<h3>My Heading</h3>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec convallis nunc malesuada, aliquam leo nec, auctor sem</p>
```

Comment: Understood. But the alternative is only having the border on the first letter which is not what the design mock up is, so not acceptable.  Thanks though.

Comment: @hnnnng Your posted sample only has the border over the first letter, so that's what I assumed you wanted. You didn't say how long you wanted the border to be.

Comment: 20px by 3px is what's requested. The width might be changed to a percentage since some of the headings are longer.

Comment: @hnnnng `20%` isn't `20px`. Please be consistent.

Comment: 20px is what's requested in the design but I am trying to change that to a percentage instead of fixed pixels. That's what I meant and your answer is actually acceptable. I just noticed you swapped the position of the heading and the ::before pseudo. That fixed the issue, THANK YOU! :D